# Read XML document with LINQ TO XML

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

I have a little XML placed into a string, called myContent:

```
 <People xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <Person ID="1" name="name1" />
     <Person ID="2" name="name2" />
     (....)
     <Person ID="13" name="name13" />
     <Person ID="14" name="name14" />
 </People>
```

and in C# I have stored previous XML content in the string variable like below:

```
        private string myContent = String.Empty +
        "<People xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" +
        "<Person ID=\"1\" name=\"name1\" />" +
        "<Person ID=\"2\" name=\"name2\" />" +
        (...)
        "<Person ID=\"13\" name=\"name13\" />" +
        "<Person ID=\"14\" name=\"name14\" />" +
        "</People>";
```

and I load as below:

```
 XDocument contentXML = XDocument.Parse(myContent);
```

then I iterate over all them:

```
 IEnumerable<XElement> people = contentXML.Elements();
 foreach (XElement person in people)
 {
     var idPerson = person.Element("Person").Attribute("ID").Value;
     var name = person.Element("Person").Attribute("name").Value
     // print the person ....
 }
```

The problem is that I only obtain the first person, not the rest. It says people has 1 element and it should have 14.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have a String.Empty at the beginning?

Comment: It is not necesary String.empty but do you think is the cause?

Comment: Could be, the code looks ok to me

Comment: `String.Empty` at the start has zero effect as it is nothing but an empty string. You could concatenate that anywhere in any string and it would not do anything, because it's empty, by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are asking for `Elements()` from the document root. There is only one element at this point, `People`.

What you actually want to do is something like:

```
var people = contentXML.Element("People").Elements()
```

Therefore, your loop would look something like:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> people = contentXML.Element("People").Elements();
foreach ( XElement person in people )
{
    var idPerson = person.Attribute( "ID" ).Value;
    var name = person.Attribute( "name" ).Value;
    // print the person ....
}
```

This will iterate over each of the `Person` elements as you intend.

Comment: As you say, Element("People") was missed between contentXML and Elements(). Now it works, thanks!

Comment: @user1624552: You are very welcome. It's easy to miss these things sometimes.